# If a pod is allocated on to on-demand instance, shall we set its priority and priority class?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

If a pod is allocated on to on demand instance, shall we set its priority and priority class?

Will preemption happens only on spot instance or on-demand instance as well?

Answer (score 0):

`Will preemption happens only on spot instance or on-demand instance as well?`

No, this is a cluster wide feature and is not bound to node type. Spot instance can be [interrupted](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-interruptions.html) anytime. For workload that you expect must run till complete (eg. job), you can use `nodeSelector` to ensure they only run on-demand node.